# python assigment of dataframes points to the same direction?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am debugging a python script that uses dataframes and there is a line like this

```
df=myObject.df
df["error_value"] = ""
```

myObject is an object that has a dataframe as a member variable (df)

I run it until the first line and sure enough `df` has the same value as `myObject.df` and the `error_value` column is not yet added.
Then I run the next line and the `df` has an empty column `error_value`

But then if I do `myObject.df.error_value` I can see that this column has been added too. So I am preplexed.

I thought df was a *copy* of the internal dataframe of the object. But is it just pointing to the same place? (as pointers in C?)

Comment: This is how it works, to have a copy you would have needed `df = myObject.df.copy()`

Comment: @mozway Interesting, I completely forgot about that. Talking in technical terms, does that mean that both are like C pointers pointing to the same memory location?

Comment: Yes, in python terms both **names** are pointing to the same **object**.